# What statistical test should I use to test the impact of Debt ratios (has 4 types of ratios) on Liquidity ratios (has 5 types of ratios) of 5 sectors?

Tags: statistics, regression, hypothesis-testing

What statistical test should be used to test the impact of Debt ratios (which has 4 types of ratios ) on Liquidity ratios (Which has 5 types of ratios) of 5 different sectors.

I gathered data of 6 years from 15 companies from each sector (so total, I gathered data from 75 companies). First, I calculated each ratios mean for each company and used that means to calculate each sector's means, standard deviation and so on, which can be found in the images. Are this information sufficient for the relevant statistic test that you might suggest to examine the impact.
[descriptive data page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn1II.jpg)[descriptive data page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouxMc.jpg)

Please advice on what statistics model should be used and how I should arrange the data to test that impact.